Effect of sample size on BIC
The BIC is given by
$$BIC = k\ln(n)-2\ln(\hat{L}).$$
Let's say I have a Gaussian model to which I'm fitting a dataset-- pretty typical stuff. The log-likelihood for the Gaussian model is given by
$$\log(\hat{L}) = -\frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi\sigma^2)-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2}{2\sigma^2}.$$
One can see very clearly that both terms scale linearly with $n$, whereas the first term in the BIC penalizing the number of parameters scales as $\ln(n)$. This means that the number of parameters in the model quickly becomes irrelevant when performing model selection for models learned on a large dataset. What is the correct approach to model selection in this regime?
Moreover, in experimental applications, the number of data points is often somewhat arbitrary (at least it is in my use case). Imagine two models, one simple and one with some redundancies. While the BIC may pick out the simpler model for fewer data points, I can arbitrarily increase preference for the more complex model just by taking more data. However, nothing fundamental about the system I'm studying has changed, and presumably the simpler model is the better one regardless of how many times you repeat your experiment. How does one reconcile this with statistical methods for model selection like the BIC?

Remember that what matters is not the absolute value of BIC for one model, but the difference between two models.
Suppose you have two Gaussian models where one of them contains $p$ important predictors and the other contains those same predictors plus $q$ predictors that actually have no additional information in them -- that is, from testing point of view the null hypothesis of extra predictors being useless is true.  Wilks' theorem tells us that the difference in log likelihoods between those models has a $\chi^2_q$ distribution for large $n$ and so is bounded in probability as $n$ increases.  Any penalty function that increases with $n$ will eventually prefer the simpler model.  On the other hand, if the null hypothesis is false, the difference in log likelihoods will increase proportional to $n$ and BIC will prefer the more complex model.
To be specific (update), consider the simplest case. Model 1 has $E[Y|X]=\alpha$, model 2 has $E[Y|X]=\alpha+\beta x$, and the true value of $\beta$ is zero.
Let $Q_1$ be the residual sum of squares for model 1 and $Q_2$ for model 2. Write $\sigma^2$ for the true residual variance, which is the same in both models.
We know that $E[Q_1/(n-1)]=\sigma^2$ and $E[Q_2/(n-2)]=\sigma^2$. Therefore, $E[Q_1]=(n-1)\sigma^2$ and $E[Q_2]=(n-1)\sigma^2$. The difference between these expectations is $\sigma^2$, which does not increase with $n$. Plugging these into BIC, we get that
$$E[BIC_1]=n\log\sigma^2+ n-1+\log n$$
and
$$E[BIC_2]=n\log\sigma^2+ n-2+ 2\log n$$
The expected difference is
$$E[\Delta]=E[BIC_2]-E[BIC_1]=\log n-1$$
so that as $n$ increases we will prefer model 1.
However, if $\beta\neq 0$ then the RSS for model 1 is larger than the RSS for model 2, by something like $\beta^2n\mathrm{var}[X]$, and BIC will prefer model 2 as $n$ increases.
In the borderline cases where $\beta\sim \sqrt{\log n/n}$ things get more interesting and a more subtle argument will be needed.=
More sophisticated versions of that sort of argument show that when you have a fixed set of $K$ models and one of them is the true model that BIC will asymptotically pick the true model with probability going to 1.
Now, in reality we don't have a fixed set of models with one of them being the true model, so this is not precisely relevant, but it at least shows something basically sensible happens as $n$ increases.

Thanks for the help! I understand that in principle, if the null model is true, $\Delta L$ should be bounded in probability given Wilks'. However, I'm having some trouble seeing this manifest practically. In the Gaussian example, it appears $\Delta L$ still goes up with n, given that $\sigma^2$ remains more or less constant? Example 16.2 in van der Vaart further shows that this LR statistic is given by $2n$ times the KL divergence between densities yielded by the two different sets of parameters, which again appears to go up as $n$. Sorry if trivial, but what am I missing here?

Thanks for the update!! I see that this works out well with expectation values, but with real data we work with specific instances of fitted parameters, among whose ranks is $\sigma^2$. When fitting the two linear models in your example, even if the null is true, we are going to run into different (even if very slightly so) $\sigma^2$s, which we then sub into our BIC. When the difference is nonzero, we will in practice find that the $\Delta L$ does go up with $n$. Apologies if I'm missing something basic, but how is one to apply the BIC when working with real data?
